# Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property dateEmp;

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-data-jpa

a java ee project using spring framework (spring-boot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set global date-time formats via the application properties file as below:
spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add this for the mentioned date format and for more details you can refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true));
}
```

Comment: so I just add this in my EmployeController.java and that's it !?